# how to covert ndarray object of numpy module to string in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have ndarray object of modules and i want to covert it to a string.
for example i want to go from:

```
[[array(['img_10.jpg'], dtype='<U22')]
 [array(['img_11.jpg'], dtype='<U22')]
 [array(['img_12.jpg'], dtype='<U22')]
 [array(['img_13.jpg'], dtype='<U22')]]
```

to only a list [`'img_10.jpg','img_11.jpg','img_12.jpg','img_13.jpg']`

how can i do that to be able to read the images with its names??

More details:

[image]

showing the content of array gives:

[image]

after trying :

```
python_list = [k for a in lst for k in a]
```

[image]

i'm still having a list of type ndarray

Comment: What happens if you have more than one element in the list?

Comment: For example: `[np.array(['img_10.jpg'], dtype='<U22'), np.array(['img_10.jpg'], dtype='<U22')]`?

Comment: Another interesting input is: `[np.array(['img_10.jpg', 'img_11.jpg'], dtype='<U22'), np.array(['img_10.jpg'], dtype='<U22')]`

Comment: that's what i have exactly

Comment: Well add those examples as input to the question, with the corresponding output

Comment: because it was a matlab file of the names of the images in a dataset when i read it in python i got  ndarray object of modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a simple comprehension, because numpy arrays are iterables. Assuming that your list is `arr`:

```
python_list = [k for a in arr for k in a]
```

Above assumed a simple array. Per your edit, you have a top 2D array of shaped (2338, 1). In that case, you will have to unpack another level:

```
python_list = [k for a in arr for b in a for k in b]
```

Comment: i tried it. The result is a list of ndarray and i want a list of string

Comment: @BayaLina: could you provide an example that I could use to reproduce? In my tests I did get a list of strings... What are you calling *modules* in your question?

Comment: I edited my question and added some screenshots so you can have a clear idea.

Comment: @BayaLina: it seems that you have an additional level to unpack. See my edit...

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by an additional level to unpack??

Comment: @BayaLina: my edit added an additional `for` in the comprehension...

Comment: it's working!!!! OMG @SergeBallesta you made my day.. I'm so grateful for your help.